# What does <int> <logical operator> <str> do in python?

Tags: python, operators

I just saw an expression like `1 and "b"` in `python` code and even `1 and "a" or "b"`.

I checked the `help` for `int` and figured out that `and` means bitwise and with two integers

```
__and__(...)
 |      x.__and__(y) <==> x&y
```

but there's no mention of a `str` as second operand. I assume that there's no way that the `str` can be interpreted as `int` because there's just no way of conversion or casting and that I'm thus missing a meaning of `and`.

Then I started experimenting to get the first expression above to be `1`, but no success.

Comment: No, `&` is bitwise - `x and y` is really `x if bool(x) else y`.

Comment: This is just boolean logic. `and` returns the first argument if that is true, otherwise the second argument.

Comment: `and` and `__and__` are different things.

Comment: @DanielRoseman how come `'foo' and 1` returns `1` even though `'foo'` evaluates `True`?

Comment: Argh, wrong way round. it returns the first argument if that is *false*, otherwise the second.

Answer (score 1):

`__and__` is used for the [*bitwise* operator `&`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations). `and` is a [*logical, boolean* operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations), and is not handled by a special method, because it short-circuits (if the first expression evaluates to false, the second expression is not even executed).

You simply have a boolean expression, and the standard [truth value testing rules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) apply here.